# CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed

Tags: unity-game-engine, gradle, androidx

I am new to unity. I am using unity **2021.3.10f1** I made my own game and added advertising and other features. When trying to build, it shows the error `"CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed."` Can you help? An error that is shown in unity:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
D:\HappyWin\Unity and projects\2021.3.10f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "D:\HappyWin\gradle-6.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
```

```
stderr[

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':launcher:lintVitalRelease'.
> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
  The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0, androidx.core:core:1.2.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.2.0, androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.0.0, androidx.tracing:tracing:1.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0
```

Changed gradle to different versions. Did not help.

Comment: Turn off all the other options except custom Manifest if you're using Unity 2020

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.